# Why does `C-h b` show `??` as the command name for my key binding?

Tags: key-bindings, commands, help

I've just added a nice custom key binding:

```lisp
;; Open files in dired mode using 'open'
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(progn
     (define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "z")
       (lambda () (interactive)
         (let ((fn (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
           (start-process "default-app" nil "open" fn))))))
```

https://jblevins.org/log/dired-open

Now, on `dired`, I look at `C-h b` (show all key bindings) but this new custom binding on the "z" key is shown as bound to `??` in the listing.

So, my question is, **how can one add a bit of documentation to a custom key binding, which will be displayed in the "show all key bindings" list?**

Perhaps does one have to give the function a global name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't bind keys to anonymous functions -- <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> can't tell you the name of the command, because you didn't name it!

Define a named function (give it a docstring too), and bind your key to that symbol.

(Also notice how unhelpful the <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>z</kbd> help is with your current code.  The suggested changes will fix that too.)

Comment: Thank for your input!  So, I wonder what the naming convention is. I'm afraid of creating a global name, which may cause future name clash. Because this function is used only under the dired mode, I hope the name exists only in that mode. [I know very little about elisp.]

Comment: Virtually all functions and variables are in the respective global name spaces in Emacs.  It might sound alarming, but it's basically fine in practice.  You do indeed (simply) have to name things sensibly.  I always suggest using a prefix of `my-` for all custom symbols.